# Angular form emit valueChanges on load if the form-control is not referred in view(html)

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using Angular FormGroup and my code is given below

component.ts

```js
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
                name: ['', [], FieldValidators.required],
                description: ['', [], FieldValidators.required],
                type: ['', []],
                field1: ['', []]
            });

this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
        alert("Dirty");
    });
```

component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="formSection">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" formControlName="name">
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description" formControlName="description">
        <input type="text" id="type" name="type" formControlName="type">
</form>
```

When I load this form, the 'Dirty' alert pops up without changing any values.

If I remove the `field1` (which is not referred in html it works as expected (no alert pops up on load).

How can I stop the emit **valueChanges** on load?

Comment: Can you remove all your formControl custom validatior and check ?

Comment: No change in behaviour

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Do you have more code to show to us? I tested your code and the alert is not called.